# PDFTron Webviewer - Thumbnail drag and drop moving

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, pdftron

in PDFTron Viewer 2.2.2, we added the drag and drop in thumbnails to move pages.

But in 3.0.1 and 3.1.0, this is not possible. Are you block the drag and drop events? (all browser are impacted)

here the code in our config.js

```
$uidisplay = $("#ui-display");
      $uidisplay.on("dragstart", function(event) {
   try{
      if($.type(event.originalEvent.dataTransfer)!="undefined"){
         event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData("text","");
         event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setDragImage(dragImg, 10, 10);
      }
   }
   catch (e) {
      e.message;
   }
   $dragCanvas = _createCanvas();
   $thumbnailsPane.scroll(_paneOnScroll);
   $(".ui-state-selected",$thumbnailsPane).css({"opacity" : "0.4"});
});
      $uidisplay.on("dragover", function(event) {
   var $context = event.target==$thumbnailsPane.get(0) ? $(event.target) : $(event.target).parents("#thumbnailView");
   var changeClass = false;
   if($context.length){
      changeClass = _setOnDragSelector(event.originalEvent ? event.originalEvent : event);
      if(event.target==$thumbnailsPane.get(0)){
         changeClass  = false;
         _scrollViewPane(event);
      }
   }
   if(!changeClass){
      $(".ui-state-drag-enter-left",$thumbnailsPane).removeClass("ui-state-drag-enter-left");
      $(".ui-state-drag-enter-right",$thumbnailsPane).removeClass("ui-state-drag-enter-right");
   }
   if((ondragCount++)%10==0){
      //console.log("ondragCount");
      $dragCanvas.css({'top' : (event.originalEvent.clientY + 10) + "px", 'left' : (event.originalEvent.clientX + 10) + "px"});
   }
});
      $uidisplay.on("dragend", function(event) {
   //console.log("dragend : " + $(event.target).prop("tagName"));
   onScrollCount = 0;
   ondragCount = 0;
   $dragCanvas.remove();
   $dragCanvas = null;
   var $target = $(".ui-state-drag-enter-left,.ui-state-drag-enter-right");
   if($target.length && $target.hasClass("thumbContainer") && Number($thumbnailsPane.attr("drag-enter-id"))>=0){
      _movePages();
   }else{
      _endOnDragSelector();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is happening because of code that was added in WebViewer to prevent the page from moving around when using the desktop viewer with a touch screen.

One way you could work around this behavior is to switch to the "Pan" tool when hovering over the thumbnails and switch back when moving back to the document. This works because the Pan tool doesn't have the same event prevention code. Here is the code you could add to your config file:

```
$(document).on('documentLoaded', function() {
  var oldToolMode;

  $('#thumbnailView').on('mouseenter', function() {
    oldToolMode = readerControl.getToolMode();
    readerControl.setToolMode('Pan');
  });

  $('#thumbnailView').on('mouseleave', function() {
    readerControl.setToolMode(oldToolMode);
  });
});
```